# SQL: IN statement equivalent for logical AND

Tags: sql

I currently use a software where there are relations between objects and tags in a SQL table as below:

```
+-----------+--------+
| object_id | tag_id |
+-----------+--------+
|       226 |     31 |
|       226 |     35 |
|       313 |     31 |
|       312 |     35 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Getting all the object ids for a list of tag ids with a logical OR is fine with the following request:

```
select distinct object_id from tags_link where tag_id in (31, 35);
```

How can all the object ids for a list of tag ids with a logical AND can be obtained?

For the above table, a request for tag ids 31 and 35 should only return object_id 226.

Comment: It's called "relational division"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select object_id
from tags_link
where tag_id in (31,35)
group by object_id
having count(distinct tag_id) = 2
```

Comment: That's a nice one! Didn't think of that. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
select   object_id from tags_link where tag_id = 31
intersect
select   object_id from tags_link where tag_id = 35
```

Comment: That's a nice one! Didn't think of that.